To find old images in chat, you still have to search with the Imgur URL
I was recently looking for a graph I had posted to a private chat room several months ago. In order to find it, I went to search for messages posted by me containing i.sstatic.net in the room I knew I was in.
However, that turned up no results.
On a search for i.stack.imgur.com, however, suddenly what I needed was showing up - despite the image links themselves having been changed to the SStatic hosting. Somehow, chat search still thinks the message contains the Imgur URL.
This can be seen in any room, such as in the Tavern. Old images and onboxes come up with results, despite the images themselves having been rewritten - hovering over an image in those search results tells you it'll go to SStatic, not Imgur.
I'm not sure what's causing this, and it's not high priority, but it is an oddity that ideally would be fixed.

Looks like they just didn't overwrite the links in the index table used for the chat search.
